# Delete record that has a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm having issues with my DELETE, If a record has a FK the record won't delete, I have tried to implement a Soft delete approach by adding a bit IsDeleted column and setting the rules.. but that also is in vain.. here is my code

```
// DELETE: api/ProductCategory/5
[Authorize]
[ResponseType(typeof(Product_Category))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete_Product_Category(int id)
{
    Product_Category Product_Category = await db.Product_Category.FindAsync(id);

    if (CRM_Product_Category == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    db.Product_Category.Remove(Product_Category);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(Product_Category);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

private bool Product_CategoryExists(int id)
{
    return db.Product_Category.Count(e => e.ProductCategoryID == id) > 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your exception or issue?

Comment: Hello @EmreSavcı I'm getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" in the console and this "<Error>
<Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message>
</Error>"

Comment: @David You used `[Authorize]` attribute , so need check current user `Permission`

Comment: @Hossein yes correct, user must be logged in... i am able to delete a record, but if that record id is elesewhere i cannot delete the record, that's when i get an error

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, you are trying to delete a **category**, but how the DB is supposed to handle **products** linked to that specific category ?

You have 2 choices here :

> 1 - Checking if you have products linked to the category and delete
>   them or change the category.
>
> 2 - Deleting on cascade. (It will delete your linked records on
>   cascade BE CAREFULL)

Comment: Hi @Cesar I like your 1st approach and also mentioned about changing the category.. do i change it to a null value? regards

Comment: If it's acceptable for your concerns and for your database settings, you can set category to null of course.